# MVVM architecture - WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF. I have to do one WPF application in MVVM Architecture.

Previously, i done some projects in 3-tier architecture(web apps) but not in MVVM & WPF.

Now i want to develop WPF application in MVVM.(I have some knowledge on WPF)

Can you please suggest me any reference links to learn WPF with MVVM arch.

Comment: Bad question for this site mate. This is opinion based, and a simple google will serve you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=learn+mvvm) would do

[MVVM in 5 minutes - http://visualstudiomagazine.com/](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/mvvm-in-5-minutes.aspx)

[MVVM Pattern - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

[Learn MVVM with Video](http://vimeo.com/20347067)